# Barchart must not render empty bars - JQPlot

Tags: javascript, charts, render, jqplot, bar-chart

I have a scenario with JQPlot's barchart where if the series data is 0 or null, it should not render the space for the barchart at all. [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q31zkh2g/),

```
please feel free to fiddle with it!
OR
```

```js
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var s1 = [20, 60, 70, 80];
var s2 = [30, 10, 20, 10];
var s3 = [10, 20, 10, 10];
var s4 = [50, 1, undefined, undefined];
var s5 = [undefined, 1, 20, undefined];

var ticks = ['1999', '2004', '2009', '2014'];

plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5], {
  // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
  animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
  seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
    pointLabels: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  axes: {
    xaxis: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
      ticks: ticks
    }
  },
  highlighter: {
    show: false
  }
});

$('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
  $('#info1').html('series: ' + seriesIndex + ', point: ' + pointIndex + ', data: ' + data);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.cursor.js"></script>


<div id="chart1" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:600px; height:300px;"></div>
```

This is the result I get:
[image]

And this is the result I desire:
[image]

As you can see it does not render the empty or 0 bars

Comment: Personally I think the rendering of the empty bars is a good feature, as it enables you to easily see how the values have changed for that series over the years. Not rendering an empty value means it's not as easy to see how that series has changed. That's my opinion anyway!

Comment: In this scenario it is necessary for me to be able to not render those bars. I understand and agree with you, But some cases like mine, Things like this is necessary